# UI responsiveness and javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have a large set of data to be plotted on google map. Because of the data set size, google map always freezes for a few seconds before all the points are plotted. I used an animated spinning circle during the loading time to show it's in progress. But end users prefer to see actions. They want data plotted on the map step by step, instead of all at a once. Since javascript doesn't support multithreading, what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: I've not messed with Google Maps. How much of this is in your control and how much of it is in Google's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript engine executes functions one by one by taking them from sort of a queue. Functions can be put there either by your script or as result of user's actions (event handlers). So idea is to split long-running task into small short-running subtasks and feed them into this 'queue' in the manner so they can be mixed with functions responding to user's action.
This can be done by calling window's setTimeout with zero delay and passing your sub-task as a function. Thus you will give a chance for UI event handler to be executed earlier

```
function plotSpot(spot) {
    // adding spots to map
};
var spots = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var plotSpotsBatch;
plotSpotsBatch = function() {
    var spotsInBatch = 10;
    while(spots.length > 0 && spotsInBatch--) {
        var spot = spots.shift();
        plotSpot(spot);
    }
    if (spots.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(plotSpotsBatch, 0);
    }
};
plotSpotsBatch();
```

Here is extension for Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.forEachInBatches = function(batchSize, func) {
    var arr = this;
    var i = 0;
    var doer;
    doer = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            for (var stopBatch = i + batchSize; i < stopBatch && i < arr.length; i++) {
                func(arr[i], i);
            }
            if (i < arr.length) {
                doer();
            }
        }, 0);
    };
    doer();
};
```

Usage example (you have to have div with id 'spots' somewhere in document). To see the difference, set batch size equal to number of spots:

```
var spots = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    spots.push('{x: ' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 180) + ', y: ' + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 180) + '}');
}
spots.forEachInBatches(10, function(spot, i) {
    document.getElementById('spots').innerHTML += spot + (i < spots.length ? '; ' : '');
});
```

Comment: I like this solution. it's simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Could you plot them in batches, with a short delay (`setTimeout`) between each one?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript might not support multiple threads normally, but you can achieve the effect.

```
function spawnThread(func, params){
   window.setTimeout(
      (function(f, p){
        return function(){
          f.call(p);
        }
      )(func, params), 0
   )
 }
```

The main problem with this method would, of course, be checking on the success of the thread, I assume you could manage this using a global variable or something similar, wouldn't be a great solution, but it would work.

Comment: Setting timeout doesn't create any new threads (JavaScript runs in  abrowser in a single thread always). Instead using this technique you devide a long task into smaller one and postpone their execution untill before the previous one is executed and the browser has made a brief.

Comment: setTimeout doesn't actually spawn threads, though.  setTimeout defers execution until at least the specified number of milliseconds has passed.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what musicfreak said, but doesn't require Gears, is [Javascript web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_DOM_workers). This is only implemented in the latest versions of browsers for now though.