# how to reduce this javascript code's cpu usage?

Tags: javascript, performance, cpu-usage

nowadays i am optimizing some js code.
there is a function named appendXYZ,and it is invoked in a loop with other functions.
it looks like as the following:

```
function OuterFunc (){
  for(...){// about 150 times
     ...
     appendXYZ();
     //other dependent functions
     ...
  }
}
```

and now i am pretty sure that appendXYZ cause high cpu usage - it can reach 50%,
but if i remove this function,cpu usage is only 1%.
when the cpu usage is 50%,the browser is nearly frozen and the page is lack of responsiveness.
what is more ,the OuterFunc execute every 20 seconds and appendXYZ is from a third party script code and i cant modify it.
**so how to optimize this code?**

now i am trying to use setTimeout but i dont know whether it works.

Comment: But what does appendXYZ do? Knowing it gets executed 150 times doesn't help much.

Comment: So you're basically asking "how do I make code I cannot modify faster"?

Comment: You could use web workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers. But the loop itself can probably not be optimized, you need to optimize `appendXYZ`.

Comment: appendXYZ is a wrapped function and it is a little complicated.it find all marker node in the map and set theri position. this code based on google map(baidu map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what that function does, but you could try making its invocation asynchronous.

It may or may not work, and it will still require the same amount of CPU, but it should at least free up the browser a bit.

```
function OuterFunc (){
  for( var i = 0; i < 150; i++ ){
     // ...
     setTimeout( appendXYZ, 0 );
     //other dependent functions
     // ...
  }
}
```

Again this may break the function. Can't tell without seeing more code.

If you're passing arguments, then you'd need something like:

```
function invoker( j ) {
   return function() {
       appendXYZ( j );
   };
}

function OuterFunc (){
  for( var i = 0; i < 150; i++ ){
     // ...
     setTimeout( invoker( i ), 0 );
     //other dependent functions
     // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that freeze the browser even quicker? I mean this way the `OuterFunc` executes faster, but the browser hangs on all of the `appendXYZ` **simultaneous** calls.

Comment: @goin_13: Nothing in a single-threaded environment is simultaneous. The CPU usage shouldn't be any (or much) better or worse overall. It just allows the browser a chance to redraw, so it seems more responsive to the end user. Ultimately there isn't enough information to give an actual optimization solution.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ it works,the current usage is less than 20%, and the browser is responsive.

Comment: @simonxu: Glad it worked, though I'm a little surprised that the CPU was decreased. Doesn't matter I guess. ;)

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ i edit your post. and i did it this way,make 3 'queue',execute appendXYZ async

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing you can do to optimize the actual code, you can spread around the execution  of the loop iterations to keep the browser responsive. According to [Robert Miller's paper](http://www.mattson.com.au/robert/files/Miller1968.pdf), the maximum amount of time you can hold up a UI and still have it feel responsive to the user is 100 milliseconds. For a technique of how to do this using `setTimeout` see [UI responsiveness and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957810/ui-responsiveness-and-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

A possibility is that the `OuterFunc` execution time is bigger that it's repetition interval.
In other words, the `OutherFunc` takes longer than 20 milliseconds to execute and being called every 20 seconds it will produce a **[stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)** exception because the function is being called before it finished it's execution in an infinite loop.
If you are using `setInterval` to execute the `OuterFunc` function every 20 milliseconds, this can be fixed by using `setTimeout` calls to simulate the `setInterval` function :

```
(function helper(){
    OutherFunc();
    // after the OutherFunc is done executing, trigger it after 20 milliseconds
    setTimeout(helper, 20);
})();
```

This might help you only if the `setInterval` is the cause of the browser freeze.
If this doesn't help you and if you don't care that much about old browsers, maybe you could implement a sort of "*threading*" using [web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers). This way your code gets executed in different threads which will definitely speed up your app (a.k.a bye bye browser freeze).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean 20 milliseconds perhaps :)